# Floating point behavior in Python 2.6 vs 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point, python-2.6, floating-accuracy

So I break out the Python 2.6 interpreter and I get this:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Nov 22 2013, 12:16:22) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 2.1
2.1000000000000001
>>> 2.2
2.2000000000000002
>>> 2.2
2.2000000000000002
```

However in Python 2.7 I get more human-like results like below:

```
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 5.4
5.4
>>> 1.1
1.1
>>> 0.2
0.2
>>>
```

I 'd like to ask why is this happening and how could I possibly make Python 2.6 behave like 2.7?

Comment: Are you aware that 2.7 is just lying to you, and not actually more accurate?

Comment: @Wooble: It's true that 2.7 is not more accurate, but 2.6 and 2.7 are both lying. Pretty much anything that uses binary floating point is lying, in the sense you're talking about. (And 2.7 actually does *round* more accurately than 2.6, as defined by the IEEE spec.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `float.__repr__()` and `float.__str__()` methods in Python 2.7 changed; the Python 3.1 float-to-string conversion method was backported and values are now rounded.

The C source code for `float.__str__()` formats a floating point value using the `g` formatter code to the `sprintf()` function, with a precision of 12 positions.

To get the same result in Python 2.6, you'll have to format the string yourself:

```
'%.12g' % fp_value
```

or use the `format()` function:

```
format(fp_value, '.12g')
```

Note that in Python 2.7 only the *representation* changed, not the actual values. Floating point values are still binary approximations of real numbers, and binary fractions don't always add up to the *exact* number represented.

If you need to have more precision than what `float` approximations offer you, you need to switch to using the [`decimal.Decimal()` type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) instead. This maintains precision, at the cost of speed (floating point arithmetic is handled in hardware on modern computers).

Comment: Thanks! I just need a precision of 2 positions and not 12. In Python 2.6.. (representation-wise as you said)

Comment: @Konos5: the value will be rounded to at most 12 digits; try it out.

Comment: True. It works..! However the result in a string. Any ideas on how I could turn that back to a (twisted sense of) proper float..?

Comment: @Konos5: You cannot. That's not what a floating point value **is**. The values in Python 2.6 and 2.7 haven't changed, only their string *representation*. You are misunderstanding how floating point values *work*.

Comment: @Konos5: This is what Wooble and John Y are referring to in their comments.

Comment: @Konos5: Try this: `format(fp, '.53f')` in both Python 2.6 and 2.7, to print a floating point value with maximum decimals, and you'll see that *both* are still approximations.

Comment: I think I get your point. The number hasn't changed. Just its representation which btw can be manipulated through the format function..! If only the format function would return 'pseudo'-floats..

Comment: @Konos5: you may want the decimal module if you want actual numbers with only 2 digits of precision.