# Why does the print function in Python3 round a decimal number?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

If i run following on python2.7 console it giving me output as:

```
>>> 1.2 - 1.0
0.19999999999999996

>>> print 1.2 - 1.0 
0.2
```

While i am running same operation in python3.5.2

```
>>> 1.2 - 1.0
0.19999999999999996

>>> print(1.2 - 1.0)
0.19999999999999996
```

I want to know why in python2.7.12 print statement giving me only 0.2 but in python3.5.2 print function giving me 0.19999999999999996.

Comment: It's the same number internally, but they changed the display logic. I'm pretty sure this has been asked before, but I can't find a good dupe target.

Comment: It looks like it's possibly related to [this issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue1580)

Comment: yes t @mgilson you are right :)

Comment: printing is not showing you all the digits. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345334/strange-behaviour-with-floats-and-string-conversion)

Comment: You should go read up on the differences between Python2 and Python3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of _[Floating point behavior in Python 2.6 vs 2.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643386/floating-point-behavior-in-python-2-6-vs-2-7)_.

Comment: yes i got my answer from [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643386/floating-point-behavior-in-python-2-6-vs-2-7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not due to the change in the `print` but changes in the `__str__` function of `floats` which print implicitly calls. Hence, when you do print, it makes a call like:

```
# For Python 2.7
>>> print (1.2 - 1.0).__str__()
0.2
```

In order to display the floating values as it is, you may explicitly call `.__repr__` as:

```
>>> print (1.2 - 1.0).__repr__()
0.19999999999999996
```

For more details, check [Martjin's answer on *Floating point behavior in Python 2.6 vs 2.7*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20643554/2063361) which states:

> In Python 2.7 only the representation changed, not the actual values. Floating point values are still binary approximations of real numbers, and binary fractions don't always add up to the exact number represented.

Answer (score 0):

`print` in Python2.7 rounds float numbers. Actually, the numbers 1.2 and 0.2 can't be represented exactly in memory (they are infinite fractions in the binary code). Therefore in order to output it correctly some output functions in programming languages may use the round. `print` in Python2.7 uses the round, but `print` in Python3.x doesn't.

Comment: All this answer does is restate the question.

Comment: Your answer is right and its a shame that people are down voting you for giving the same answer as the person that's being upvoted.